# ADF HANA View partition columns

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, hana

I am trying to extract data from  a HANA view using ADF HANA connector. In the partition option(inside copy activity), I am using dynamic range partitioning by passing a partition column. While doing so, I am getting the below error :-

> ErrorCode=SapHanaFailToGetBoundsDueToInvalidQuery,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Fail
> to get bounds by using query. Make sure your query can be nested while
> using partition reading and your partition column data type is
> acceptable.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.SapHanaConnector,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR
> [S1000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] General error;260 invalid
> column name: FISCALYR: line 4 col 60 (at pos 530),Source=libodbcHDB.dll,'

I tried using a different partition column, but that also gives the same error. Can anyone let me know the possible cause?

Below is the copy activity input log

> {
> "source": {
> "type": "SapHanaSource",
> "query": "select\r\n"COCD" as BUKRS,\r\n"ASSETNBR" as ANLN1,\r\n"ASSETSUBNUMB" as ANLN2,\r\n"FISCALYR" as
> GJAHR,\r\n"REALDEPRAREA" as AFABE,\r\n"DEPRLASTPOST" as
> AFBLPE,\r\n"DEPRPERDPOST" as AFBANZ,\r\n"FISCALYREXPR" as
> \r\nFROM
> "_SYS_BIC"."intel.finance.private/AssetValueHistoricView" WHERE
> ?AdfHanaDynamicRangePartitionCondition",
> "partitionOption": "SapHanaDynamicRange",
> "partitionSettings": {
> "partitionColumnName": "FISCALYR"
> }
> },
> "sink": {
> "type": "ParquetSink",
> "storeSettings": {
> "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
> },
> "formatSettings": {
> "type": "ParquetWriteSettings"
> }
> },
> "enableStaging": false,
> "parallelCopies": 20,
> "translator": {
> "type": "TabularTranslator",
> "typeConversion": true,
> "typeConversionSettings": {
> "allowDataTruncation": true,
> "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
> }
> } }

Comment: In select Query, "FISCALYR" is given with alias name GJAHR. Try this name in partition Column Name.

Comment: Tried that as well, didn't work

Comment: Are you getting same error? What is the data type of that column?